# Корзина для инет магазина COOKIE

Tags: php, cookie, корзина

Делаю корзину на *куках* для интернет-магазина.

Пока вот что написал:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$size=$_POST['size'];
$color=$_POST['color'];


setcookie ("cart[id]", $id, time() + 3600);
setcookie ("cart[size]", $size, time() + 3600);
setcookie ("cart[color]", $color, time() + 3600);

if (isset($_COOKIE['cart'])) {
foreach ($_COOKIE['cart'] as $name => $value) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    echo "$name : $value <br />\n";
}
}
```

Но добавляется лишь один товар.

Понимаю, что при добавлении товара перезаписываю массив `cart` по-новой.

Подскажите как дополнять массив, а не перезаписывать его?

Comment: Задача простая. Можно, как вариант, использовать [array_push](http://www.php.su/array_push)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Делаете неправильно. Стоит человеку куку потереть и корзина пропала. Делается это иначе. Корзина храниться в базе, а ключ к ней в куке. Пока мы не знаем кто юзер (не авторизовался) юзаем ключик для идентификации, как только авторизовался - привязываем корзину к юзеру и идентифицируем уже по его ID. Шансов, что корзина пропадёт, меньше. При добавлении товаров в корзину просто добавляем товары в массив, а массив сериализуем для хранения в базе в виде TEXT, например.

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Хозяин-барин, захотел потереть куки - и потер. А, главное, та же проблема и остается: "потер куки" - а с ними и "ключик". Но главное, конечно - это фантастическая полезность ответа для 2000 посетителей, которые приходили узнать, как сделать корзину. Стак оверфлоу как мы его любим, да. Полезный сайт для людей